# pavucontrol settings change after reboot on Devuan

Tags: pulseaudio, devuan

I have 2 sound output devices on my Devuan system - Analog and HDMI Digital. When I set the pavucontrol to HDMI Digital, it always defaults to Analog after reboot, even HDMI is connected and nothing else have changed. How to make the pavucontrol keep all the settings after reboot? I only have this problem with Devuan 4 and Devuan 5. Debian 11, Debian 12 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS keep all pavucontrol settings until I change them. Is this a sysvinit (Devuan) vs. systemd (Debian, Ubuntu) problem? Thank you.